# Vagrant: failed to mount nfs shared folder (mount.nfs: Operation not permitted)

Tags: linux, mount, nfs, vagrant

Vagrant throws error message:

```
==> default: Mounting NFS shared folders...

mount -o 'vers=3,udp' 192.168.33.1:'/home/xxx/vagrant/www' /home/www
mount.nfs: Operation not permitted
```

ssh to the guest and run

```
root@debian:~# mount -o 'vers=3,udp' 192.168.33.1:'/home/xxx/vagrant/www' /home/www -v
mount: no type was given - I'll assume nfs because of the colon
mount.nfs: timeout set for Tue Jul 15 22:26:56 2014
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'vers=3,udp,addr=192.168.33.1'
mount.nfs: prog 100003, trying vers=3, prot=17
mount.nfs: trying 192.168.33.1 prog 100003 vers 3 prot UDP port 2049
mount.nfs: prog 100005, trying vers=3, prot=17
mount.nfs: trying 192.168.33.1 prog 100005 vers 3 prot UDP port 54188
mount.nfs: portmap query failed: RPC: Program/version mismatch
mount.nfs: Operation not permitted
```

`mount.nfs: portmap query failed: RPC: Program/version mismatch`
Could be a lead but didn't have luck with googling. The host (nfs server) supports nfs4 and nfs3.

---

Please feel free to ask for more information.

Comment: oh dear god!! I reboot my machine and it suddenly works.....

Comment: did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @kayaker243 no, thank god, it didn't happen again.